# In Rails 3.1 how do I show only future events?

Tags: controller, calendar, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-3.1

So I am building a calendaring application, and showing an event from the past is not as important as showing the upcoming events.

Right now I have built the model for events to show the earliest events first, but how would I hide from view any event that has passed?

Currently showing in my controller:

```
@events = Event.find(:all, :order => "start").paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

I have no idea how to remove entries that have a start date :start that is before today. For this purpose I only need to remove from view, can worry about a db delete after MVP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand all you need is condition in your `find` call:

```
@events = Event.find(:all, 
    :order => "start", 
    :conditions => ['start >= ?', Date.today]
).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

Or in more Rails 3 style:

```
@events = Event.where('start >= ?', Date.today).order(:start)
               .paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this fit the bill, and works for a map json feed declaration in the controller as well. Cheers.